# What is this series supposed to *be*?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-series

Partial integration of $\sin(x)\times 1$ results in an infinite series very similar to the Taylor series of cosine, but with some obvious differences.

$x\sin(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}\cos(x) -\frac{x^3}{3!}\sin(x)+\frac{x^4}{4!}\cos(x)+...+c$

What strikes me is the fact that this is almost identical to the Taylor series of cosine, with the $a$'s being replaced by $x$'s and the $--++$ series being shifted back by one, but this makes no sense as the indefinite integral of $\sin(x)$ is $-\cos(x)$, not $\cos(x)$.

Now, assuming I am wrong and this is indeed equal to $-\cos(x)$, I come on to my second problem: without replacing the $x$'s with constants, the series doesn't approach either, positive $\cos(x)$ or otherwise, and I can't see why not - it *is* equal to the integral of $\sin(x)$ after all. Isn't it?

I am sure this is a trivial result but I have struggled to find anything on it even in the darkest realms of triviality (i.e. Yahoo Answers), which is why I am having to ask this question.

Comment: It may interest you to know that you *can* get the Taylor series of the sine (or any function) by integration by parts: 
$$ \int_a^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(t) \, dt = f(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k. $$

Comment: @Chappers It does interest me quite a bit! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am parsing your expression properly, your series would appear to be $$\sin (x)\times \left(x-\frac {x^3}{3!}+\frac {x^5}{5!}-\cdots\right) - \cos (x)\times \left(\frac {x^2}{2!}-\frac {x^4}{4!}-\cdots\right)$$ $$=\sin^2(x) -\cos (x)\times (1-\cos(x))=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-\cos(x)=1-\cos(x)$$

Which, up to a constant, is equal to $-\cos (x)$ as desired.

Comment: Why multiply by $x -x^3/3!+x^5/5!...$ though?

Comment: It's your expression, not mine!  I just factored out the $\sin (x)$ from all the terms which had it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.. So the expression is correct, but can be simplified to equal $-cos(x)$. Sorry, didn't notice what you had done immediately.

Comment: No  problem.  Yes, I think your expression is entirely correct.  Of course there are easier ways to compute $\int \sin (x)dx$ but it's never a bad idea to see what happens when you try different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually (ignoring $c$): $$\begin{align}\sin(x)(x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!\cdots) + \cos(x)(-x^2/2!+x^4/4!\cdots) &= \sin(x)\sin(x) +\cos(x)(\cos(x)-1)\\
&=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-\cos(x)\\
&=1-\cos(x)\end{align}$$